# How to Install Dependencies from a Local Python Repository with Tox?

Tags: python, authentication, pypi, tox

## Introduction

I would like to install some dependencies (`local-package1` and `local-package2`) into a virtualenv using Tox. Those dependencies are packages that only exist on my local Python Package Index (inside of an Artifactory instance).

## Attempts

Here's my `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27
indexserver =
    LOCAL =  https://me:abc123@artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple

[testenv]
deps =
    :LOCAL:local-package1
    mock
    pykwalify
    :LOCAL:local-package2
    xlrd
    XlsxWriter
    xlwt
    yamllint
commands =
    make.sh
```

Here's the output from `tox -v`:

```
using tox.ini: repo/tox.ini
using tox-3.7.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.pyc
GLOB sdist-make: ~/repo/setup.py
  ~/repo$ /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 ~/repo/setup.py sdist --formats=zip --dist-dir ~/repo/.tox/dist >~/repo/.tox/log/tox-0.log
package .tmp/package/1/example-0.0.0.zip links to dist/example-0.0.0.zip (~/repo/.tox)
py27 cannot reuse: no previous config ~/repo/.tox/py27/.tox-config1
py27 create: ~/repo/.tox/py27
  ~/repo/.tox$ /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 -m virtualenv --python /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 py27 >~/repo/.tox/py27/log/py27-0.log
py27 installdeps: :LOCAL:local-package1, mock, pykwalify, :LOCAL:local-package2, xlrd, XlsxWriter, xlwt, yamllint
  ~/repo$ ~/repo/.tox/py27/bin/python -m pip install -i https://me:abc123@artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple local-package1 local-package2 >~/repo/.tox/py27/log/py27-1.log
```

And doing a `tail -f ~/repo/.tox/py27/log/py27-1.log` yields the following:

```
actionid: py27
msg: getenv
cmdargs: 'repo/.tox/py27/bin/python -m pip install -i https://me:abc123@artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple local-package1 local-package2'

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Looking in indexes: https://me:****@artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple, https://artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
Collecting local-package1
```

and it seems to hang indefinitely.

If I run the command:

```
repo/.tox/py27/bin/python -m pip install -i https://me:abc123@artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple local-package1 local-package2
```

outside of the virtualenv, I can install these packages without any issues.

## Question

How can I properly install dependencies with Tox which includes authentication to a Python Package Index?

Comment: Can you `pip install local-package1` from `https://me:abc123@artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple` outside of `tox`?

Comment: @phd I can install these packages outside of tox's virtualenv without any issues. I've added some words on this to my question.

Comment: Can I ask for the following experiment: `. repo/.tox/py27/bin/activate` and then `repo/.tox/py27/bin/python -m pip install -i https://me:abc123@artifactory.example.com/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple local-package1 local-package2`?